# Check widows/orphans easily in PDF preview output

Tags: viewers, widows-orphans

I'd like to know if there is a easy way to find in the PDF preview the orphans and widows (as does the draft option to search words out of the margins with a black box).

Comment: you would probably need luatex and some lua to interrogate the paragraph breaking

Answer (score 8):

Based on the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45528/finding-all-widows-and-orphans?rq=1), here is an attempt. The same caveats apply, that is you will probably get some false positives.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\clubpenalty=153
\widowpenalty=152

% check if the output penalty was due to orphan or widow or both
\ifdraft{
\def\testforwidowsandorphans{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty=152
  \marginnote{\color{green}\rule[10pt]{5pt}{5pt}}%
  % Widow
  \else
  \ifnum\outputpenalty=153
  \marginnote{\color{blue}\rule[10pt]{5pt}{5pt}}%
  % Orphan
  \else
  \ifnum\outputpenalty=305
  \marginnote{\color{red}\rule[10pt]{5pt}{5pt}}%
  % Family (orphan + widow)
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}}{\def\testforwidowsandorphans{}}

% execute this code at the very beginning of the OR
\toks0=\output
\output\expandafter{\expandafter\testforwidowsandorphans
  \the\toks0}


\newcommand\stupidpara{First line\\second line\\and final line\par}
\newcommand\verystupidpara{First line\\and final one\par}

\setlength\textheight{5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\stupidpara\stupidpara\stupidpara\stupidpara
\verystupidpara\verystupidpara\verystupidpara\verystupidpara
\end{document}
```

Orphan:

[image]

Widow (yes, it appears on the next page... I don't know if it can easily be fixed):

[image]

Orphan + widow:

[image]

(Original version of this code: [Finding all widows and orphans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45528/finding-all-widows-and-orphans?rq=1) )

Comment: oh nice you probably should change `\@medpenalty` from its default  151 though to avoid `\pagebreak[2]` (or use 152 and 153 in the above)

Comment: I don't deserve any "nice", @Frank Mittelbach does! About the overlap with other values, I understand that it is the main reason why false positives may arise. But indeed, looking at the default values for the penalties, 152 and 153 look somewhat safer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I didn't follow the link and notice you'd borrowed Frank's code:-)